I need to make a fuctional test
Context about the test:
I ask the player to move (which he does not have to do, because it is configured so that he does not do that), and that if the test is not equal to the movement coordinates, that is, he did not move, it is valid
I have zero experience using Unreal Engine 5, but I have a college project using Unreal and Meta Quest 2. I need to perform a functional test for the deliverable assignment. This is the blueprint with the idea that I have.
I need correction or how work this
Blueprint Test001
